# AngularJS ASP.Net MVC: Interaction between Treeview and Grid on the same page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, gridview, model-view-controller, treeview

I am using **AngualrJS** with **Devextreme** controls in **ASP.Net MVC** project, i have a page which contains a treeview (populating Folders) and a grid (populating folders and files in the selected node in the tree)

On item click of any node in the tree i am going to refresh the grid content.
The Tree nodes are populated using Controller "**treeCtrl**" by calling a service.

As i assume the **grid** is connected to another controller "**gridCtrl**" which calls another service with a **parameter** (which is the node id selected in the tree.

- How can i tell the grid to refresh based on selected node id in the tree?
  Assuming that the two controls and controllers are in the same page.
- What is the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, you should get a selected treeview item. For example, you can use the [onItemClick](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Configuration/?version=15_1#onItemClick) event:

```
onItemClick: function(args) {
    // here you can get the data of the item you clicked
    var itemData = args.itemData;
}
```

Next, you can filter the data grid by selected treeview item data(for the demo purposes I suppose all treeview items have the unique `id` field).

```
var gridDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
   load: function(options) {
       var filter = options.filter;
       if(filter) {
           // return filtered data
       }
       // return all data
   }
});
//...
// event handler from the previous step
onItemClick: function(args) {
    var itemId = args.itemData.id;

    // set filter for the datagrid and load datasource
    gridDataSource.filter(["folderId", itemId]);
    gridDataSource.load();
}
```

I've created a small sample here - http://plnkr.co/edit/2BBo6sPGAdNqxeij2ZM0?p=preview;

Of course, in your case you have to implement the filter operation on the server side in a mvc controller. So, you should pass the filter parameter there. It should be like below:

```
 var gridDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
   load: function(options) {
       var filter = options.filter,
           deferred = $.Deferred();
       $.ajax({
           url: "your/service/",
           data: filter
       }).done(function(response){
           deferred.resolve(response);
       });

       return deferred.promise();
   }
});
```

Also, probably, this [Add Data-Based Widgets to MVC Project](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/UI_Widgets/Add_Data-Based_Widgets_to_MVC_Project/?version=15_1#Add_Data-Based_Widgets_to_MVC_Project) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. I am trying to make the tree work in virtual mode. Loading only the root nodes first. Then, on expand children nodes will be populated after quering the Service. Nodes/GetNodes?nodeId =Selected Node. I am using the followoing   '$scope.treeOptions = {
        dataSource: treeDataSource,
        virtualModeEnabled: true,
        dataStructure: 'plain',
        rootValue: -1,
    };'             I have used the same treeDataSource you provided in the sample and tried various scenarios such as adding event onItemExpanded. Please, share you thoughts if any.